# Validate uniqueness in node.js with Joi

Tags: node.js, express, validation, unique

How to check if the incoming request value is unique or not with the help of `Joi` package.

```
exports.createUser = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().required().email(),
    password: Joi.string().required().custom(password),
    phoneNumber: Joi.string().min(10).required(),
  }),
};
```

Here I want to check if email is unique or not. I am aware that I can do this in the mongoose(Schema) but I want to do it with joi package.

The API endpoint:

```
router
  .route("/register")
  .post(validate(userValidation.createUser), User.register);
```

The register controller:

```
exports.register = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var isValidated = await userService.validateInDatabase(req);
    if (!isValidated)
      return res
        .status(409)
        .json({ error: "Phone number or email is already registered" });

    var user = await userService.create(req.body);
    var token = await sendVerification(user);
    return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

I have a function called validateInDatabase but I do not want to use it.

The userService.create service function:

```
exports.create = async (user) => {
  const hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate(user.password);

  let new_user = new User({
    phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
    email: user.email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  const payload = {
    id: new_user._id,
  };
  let JWToken = jwt.sign(payload, keys.JWToken, { expiresIn: 31556926 });
  const userData = await new_user.save();
  return { userData, JWToken };
};
```

The validate function:

```
const validate = (schema) => (req, res, next) => {
  const validSchema = pick(schema, ["params", "query", "body"]);
  const object = pick(req, Object.keys(validSchema));
  const { value, error } = Joi.compile(validSchema)
    .prefs({ errors: { label: "key" }, abortEarly: false })
    .validate(object);

  if (error) {
    const errorMessage = error.details
      .map((details) => details.message)
      .join(", ");
    return res.status(400).json({ error: errorMessage });
  }
  Object.assign(req, value);
  return next();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `custom` (for sync) or `external` validation(for async) and check the email into the database.

Something like this:

```
exports.createUser = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().required().email().external(async (email) => {
        // You have to create `checkEmailInUse` funciton somewhere in your code and call it here
        const isEmailInUse = await checkEmailInUse(email);
        if(isEmailInUse) {
            throw new Error('email in use');
        }

        return email;
    }),
    password: Joi.string().required().custom(password),
    phoneNumber: Joi.string().min(10).required(),
  }),
};
```

and here use `validateAsync` instead of `validate`

```
const validate = (schema) => (req, res, next) => {
  const validSchema = pick(schema, ["params", "query", "body"]);
  const object = pick(req, Object.keys(validSchema));
  try {
      const value = await Joi.compile(validSchema)
        .prefs({ errors: { label: "key" }, abortEarly: false })
        .validateAsync(object);
        
      Object.assign(req, value);
      return next();
  }
  catch(error) {
    const errorMessage = error.details
      .map((details) => details.message)
      .join(", ");
    return res.status(400).json({ error: errorMessage });
  }
};
```

Comment: I have created a function in the user-model file and called it as you said but it is throwing an error like ```Error: Schema with external rules must use validateAsync()```

Comment: The function: ```userSchema.statics.isEmailTaken = async function (email, excludeUserId) {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email, _id: { $ne: excludeUserId } });
  return !!user;
};```

Comment: @JohnOliver can you show me your end-point code?

Comment: @JohnOliver instead of `schema.validate()` now you have to call `schema.validateAsync()`

Comment: Where to call ```schema.validateAsync()``` because I don't have ```schema.validate()``` anywhere in my code

Comment: @JohnOliver where do you use `createUser`? Can you share the code of your end-point/controller ?

Comment: I think it should not be `validateAsync` because validate is the function that I have created. (it is not from Joi)  so If I replace it with `validateAsync` Then it is throwing an error like ```validateAsync is not defined```

Comment: can you show me what `validate`  is doing then?

Comment: I have updated the code too, it should give you the idea of how to use `validateAsync`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an async lookup through the use of `any.external()`.

Here's an example (TypeScript) checking that the username is not already used:

```js
    import Joi, { ExternalValidationFunction } from 'joi'

    // lookup function
    usernameIsAvailableOrThrow = (
        username: string
    ): Promise<ReturnType<ExternalValidationFunction>> => {
        return isUsernameTaken(username).then((isTaken) => {
            if (isTaken) {
                throw new Error('This username is already taken')
            }
            return undefined // success for joi validation
        })
    }

    // validation definition
    externalValidationObj = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().external(usernameIsAvailableOrThrow)
    })

    // run validation
    externalValidationObj.validateAsync({ username }).then(() => {
      // success
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // error
    })
```